# Adding two 2D array in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I was just wondering how I can add two 2D arrays using VBA in Excel.

I tried to search on internet and it seems to me that the only way is to loop on each element. Am I right or is there any better/faster method?

As a corollary question: it would be better to loop or to copy to Range and use PasteSpecial options as in the spirit of the answer to the question [how to add arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547033/how-to-add-arrays) ?

Comment: Depends very much on what the data elements are, how much the array will be interacting with the worksheet, etc.  You even point to an example answering your question - Anything else we say will be based on general opinions. Please research your own question for a solution first, and come here with a specific additional query about where your own solution is failing you.

Comment: The elements of the arrays are integers and the arrays have no need to interact with the worksheet. I will try to explain the spirit of my question using another example. If I want to slice a column from a 2D array I can create a loop to extract those elements or I can use the  `WorksheetFunction.Index` function to do the same thing. This second choice for me is easier and faster than whatever  I can code. Similarly I could rewrite my question as: "Is there any standard or built-in alternative to loop to add 2 arrays in VBA?"

Comment: A loop will be faster, and you can code it as a reusable standalone utility function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following Worksheetfunction method to add two VBA variant arrays:

```
Function ArrayAdd(A, B)
    ArrayAdd = Application.Pmt(, -1, A, B)
End Function
```

`A` and `B` can be arrays, ranges or values. ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/25596621/1252820)

Comment: Thanks @lori_m, that was exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Since there is considerable ambiguity about "adding arrays" assuming each is comprised of numbers only and is 3x3 in A1:C3 and A6:A8 then to output to J1:L3 please try:

```
Sub ArraySum()
Range("J1:L3").FormulaArray = "=RC[-9]:R[2]C[-7]+R[5]C[-9]:R[7]C[-7]"
End Sub
```